# Android images - onClick

Tags: android, android-layout

The reason I don't like using buttons is that background images get resized , while using imageview keeps them as-is. But doing so makes me wonder whether it's a good way of providing interface in terms of focusing. I mean is there any difference between ImageView getting focus and  TextView ?

Comment: you can set your button size in "dp" - it is good practice and background doesn't resize

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ImageButton...

You will be able to use the same properties as an ImageView.

Here is [the documentation about this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Answer (score 0):

I too mostly use `ImageView` instead of `ImageButton` i never had any problem